# Запятая перед "что" в предложении

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, синтаксис, грамматика, союзы

"Не думаю(,) что с этим надо затягивать".

Объясните, нужна ли тут запятая.

Comment: Конечно, нужна. Что тут сложного?

Comment: Нужно объяснить почему.

Answer (score 1):

Нужна, потому что это СПП (сложноподчинённое предложение) с придаточным изъяснительным. Придаточное предложение отделяется запятой от главного (*Не думаю*) и «изъясняет», чего конкретно говорящий не думает))

Comment: Как вы определили главное предложение? Где подлежащее, а где сказуемое?

Comment: «Как вы определили главное предложение?» — Элементарно, Ватсон)): о чём вообще во фразе речь? О том, что говорящий кое-что (НЕ) ДУМАЕТ. У вас на этот счёт другое мнение? Сказуемое — «думаю» (с добавлением частицы «не»), подлежащее подразумевается (но однозначно определимо по глагольной форме сказуемого).

Answer (score 1):

Я руску ниразбирась, но...

Я не думаю, что с этим надо затягивать.

Я - подлежащее (его опустили), НЕ ДУМАЮ - сказуемое. Я не думаю что? Что с этим надо затягивать.
Т.е. второе предложение подчиняется первому, раз отвечает на вопрос, идущий от него! А раз подчиняешься - знай своё место! Как указать место? Отделить... запятой!
НАДО ЗАТЯГИВАТЬ - сказуемое. Затягивать с чем? С ЭТИМ! С ЭТИМ - дополнение (наверное).

Answer (score 1):

Запятая перед "что, конечно же, нужна.
*Не думаю*, [о чём?] *что с этим надо затягивать.*

Это сложноподчиненное предложение, в котором каждая его часть представляет собой
односоставное предложение (без подлежащего):
[Я] *Не думаю* — определенно-личное (главное);
*с этим надо затягивать* — обобщенно-личное (придаточное дополнительное).

> И тогда он заговорил простыми словами и нашел в них немало увлекательного; **не думаю, что с этим выводом стоит согласиться** <...> но что здесь точно описан путь всякой плоти — грех сомневаться.
> Дмитрий Быков. Советская литература. Краткий курс. Часть 2

[Придаточные дополнительные (изъяснительные)](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/738-222_pridatochnye_dopolnitelnye_izyasnitelnye.html)