# Узнать(,) в чём проблема

Tags: пунктуация

Скажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая перед «в чём проблема».

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/471424/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8

Comment: Приведите полный текст предложения,  знаки не ставят в его отдельных фрагментах.

Comment: Прошу прощения, в ближайшее время я узнаю(,) в чём проблема и сообщу вам!

Answer (score 2):

*В ближайшее время я узнаю,* ***в чём*** (заключается) ***проблема,*** *и сообщу вам.*

Это СПП с придаточным изъяснительным, союзное слово В ЧЕМ. Предложение относится к первому из однородных сказуемых (*узнаю и сообщу*) и обособляется запятыми с двух сторон.

Comment: Благодарю! Точно, поняла!

Comment: Вот и отлично!  Обращайтесь на лучший форум по русскому языку! :))  Здесь вам быстро ответят и обязательно обоснуют свой ответ.

Comment: @Анна  На сайте принято принимать один из ответов на свой вопрос галочкой.